# updating enabled-status of QAction

Tags: python, qt, delphi, action

When Delphi introduced actions some years ago now, one of the great advantages was that the status (enabled/disabled) of the action was handled in the event loop, rather than that the programmer had to think about updating these states concommittant to all status changes of the application. For example:

`procedure TMyForm.SaveActionUpdate(Sender: TObject)
begin
    (sender as TAction).enabled := self.contentHasChanged();
end;`

instead of

`procedure TMyForm.onContentChanging(sender: TObject)
begin
    SaveAction.enabled := True;
    SaveAsAction.enabled := True;
    RevertAction ... etc.
end;`

Now I am trying to rebuild some of these old Delphi programs in Python using Qt, but so far I have failed to figure out how to enable QActions without resorting to explicitly setting it enabled whenever my content changes. What would be a fruitful approach to do this?

Comment: Of course that is available in Qt for ages: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender and you could use `qobject_cast` to get `QAction` type from `sender()`. Mind that 'onContentChanging' should be the slot function. I would give an answer to this but I only do Qt/C++.

Comment: @AlexanderVX The OP wants something like the first code fragment, **not** the second one.

Comment: I misspoke. There is a need for SaveActionUpdate slot and we can handle sender in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dived into the VCL to see how it's implemented there. I hesitated whether it would be a good idea to do so, for the concept op this framework may be well different from Qt and put me on the wrong track rather than being helpful. However, the lack of response to this question suggests to me that Qt actions just may not work this way. Which is a pity.

Delphi's VCL actions register themselves on construction in a central list that gets evaluated in the application's idle time in the event loop. This at least I found can be emulated in Qt by using a timer started with timeout 0. Thus I come to this work-around:

```
class HFClient(QMainWindow):

    def updateAction(self, action):
        action.setEnabled(False)

class ActionUpdater(QTimer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ActionUpdater, self).__init__()
        self.members = {}
        self.timeout.connect(self.timerEvent)

    def add(self, action, updateProc):
        self.members[action] = updateProc

    def remove(self, action):
        del self.members[action] 

    def timerEvent(self, unused):
        # prevent being the last one to keep the object alive:
        done = [action for action in self.members if sys.getrefcount(action) < 5]
        for action in done:
            self.remove(action)

        # call registered method:
        for action, updateProc in self.members.items():
                updateProc(action)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = HFClient()
    w.show()

    updater = ActionUpdater()
    updater.start()

    a = QAction("save as", app)
    updater.add(a, w.updateAction)
#     del a        
    app.exec()
```

Memory managed programming languages are a bit hard to have the objects unregistered again when the registered object is done for. All too easily the object is kept alive because it still has a reference in the register. I tried to circumvent this by checking the refcount vs. the number of references within the updater instance. I would value a better method for this, though.

One could make a QAction descendant that would register itself (and maybe a signal slot combination for updating).

**UPDATE**

To use the conventional signal-slot mechanism, descend from Action like

```
class UpdatedAction(QAction):
    update = pyqtSignal(QAction)

    def getUpdated(self):
        self.update.emit(self)
```

Weakrefs solve the reference counting issue in the code above:

```
class ActionUpdater(QTimer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ActionUpdater, self).__init__()
        self.members = []
        self.timeout.connect(self.timerEvent)

    def add(self, action):
        self.members.append(weakref.ref(action, self.remove))

    def remove(self, action):
        self.members.remove(action) 

    def timerEvent(self, unused):
        # call registered method:
        for action in self.members:
            action().getUpdated()
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
void MyForm::onSaveActionUpdateSlot() // must be a slot
{
    QAction* pAction = qobject_cast<QAction*>( sender() );
    if (pAction)  // if sent by QAction
       pAction->setEnbaled( this->contentHasChanged() );
}
```

Comment: If I understand this well, this defines a connection between the updateProc and the action, but not how the slot would be signalled frequently?

Comment: Unsure if I understand the question but in general: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Its not hard to have the action call the updateProc by defining a custom signal. It's not shown in my answer, but I did it already. Core of my question is: how to have the action update itself continually rather than rely on other objects to en-/disable the action when they see it fit. The action (or its delegate) oversees its environment and decides whether or not to be enabled. But it must be triggered to do so.